# Como fazer consultas especificas no sql usando o Laravel?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco para ver os aniversariante do dia do mês corrente. Uma consulta desse tipo, veja:

> `SELECT * FROM membros WHERE day(dataNasc) = day(CURRENT_DATE) and month(dataNasc) = month(CURRENT_DATE);`

Como eu poderia fazer essa consulta no Laravel?

Tentei fazer dessa forma mais ele esta voltando datas que não são de ***hoje*** (***que no caso hoje dia 03/09/2017***). Pois ele volta data como `04/09` , `05/09`, etc.

Veja como eu estou tentando :

```
$date = Membro::all();
foreach ($date as $d) {
    $explode = explode('-', $d->dataNasc);
}
$query = DB::table('membros')
           ->whereDay('dataNasc', $explode[2])
           ->whereMonth('dataNasc', $explode[1])
           ->get(['nome', 'imagem']);
dd($query);
```

Ele me retorna 4 valores. onde somente 3 valores estão de acordo com data atual no momento, mas, se eu for no `phpmyadmin` e colocar o comando

> `SELECT * FROM membros WHERE day(dataNasc) = day(CURRENT_DATE)  and month(dataNasc) = month(CURRENT_DATE);`

Ele me retorna somente os **3** valores corretos da data corrente e no mês corrente? Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Como eu poderia fazer essa consulta no Laravel?

Vou tentar responder com algumas soluções:

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM membros 
   WHERE day(dataNasc) = day(CURRENT_DATE) 
     and month(dataNasc) = month(CURRENT_DATE);
```

---

- [**Query Builder**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

***1) Com a data atual do servidor***

```
\DB::table('membros')
    ->whereDay('dataNasc', date('d'))
    ->whereMonth('dataNasc', date('m'))
    ->get();
```

***2) Com a data atual do banco de dados***

```
$where = 'day(dataNasc) = day(CURRENT_DATE)  and month(dataNasc) = month(CURRENT_DATE)';
\DB::table('membros')
    ->whereRaw($where)
    ->get();
```

---

- [**Eloquent**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent):

***1) Com a data atual do servidor***

```
Membro::whereDay('dataNasc', date('d'))
    ->whereMonth('dataNasc', date('m'))
    ->get();
```

***2) Com a data atual do banco de dados***

```
$where = 'day(dataNasc) = day(CURRENT_DATE)  and month(dataNasc) = month(CURRENT_DATE)';
Membro::whereRaw($where)->get();
```

- [**Running Raw SQL Queries (SQL Pura)**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries):

***1) Com a data atual do banco de dados***

```
$sql = ' SELECT * FROM membros WHERE day(dataNasc) = day(CURRENT_DATE) ';
$sql .= ' and month(dataNasc) = month(CURRENT_DATE) '
\DB::select($sql);
```

ou seja, nessa resposta tem 5 exemplos que tem como saída o mesmo resultado, conforme a [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) da pergunta, só verifique qual é melhor mediante os pontos: servidor onde roda a aplicação ou servidor do banco de dados, porque, podem ter diferença de data e hora.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

---

- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)
- [Database: Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)
- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)
- [Database: Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries)